# Taking the derivative to find horizontal tangent line

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Determine the point at which the graph of the function has a horizontal tangent line.
$f(x) =  \frac{5 x^2}{x^2+1}$

I figured out the derivative, $ \frac{10}{(x^2+1)^2}$, but I'm not sure where to go after this in order to find the horizontal tangent line.

Any help?

edit: fixed the denominator, that was a typo. Apologies

Comment: Solve the derivative at zero.

Comment: Your derivative is wrong. The actual derivative is $\frac {10x}{x^4+2x^2+1}$

Answer (score 2):

$f'(x) = \frac{10x(x^2+1)-2x (5x^2)}{(x^2+1)^2} = \frac{10x}{(x^2+1)^2}$ this derivative is equal to $0$ when $x=0$ and thus at $x=0$ you have horizontal tangent line.

Comment: The denominator should be squared

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal tangent line simply means 'find the points where the function reaches its maximum and minimum'. Can you find such points?